# How to delete document from mongoDB collection using the document's ID?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am trying to remove a document from a mongoDB collection by finding the document in the collection using an id. Below is a snippet of my code and it says that the note was successfully deleted but when I go back to where all the notes are displayed, the note that was supposedly deleted is still there.

```
router.post('/delete', function(req, res) {    
    notesCollection.remove(prevID, function(err, records){
        if(err){
            res.render("deleteFail.jade");                
        }
        else{                
            res.render("deleteSuccess.jade");
        }
    });  
});
```

Where prevID is the _id of the note currently trying to be deleted. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using mongoose? I am pretty certain the first argument has to be a query object, e.g. `{ _id: prevId }` and not just the id directly.